# When does UIKit remove constraints automatically

Tags: ios, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

In my updateLayoutConstraints, I am adding constraints, and then I call `super.updateLayoutConstraints()`. According to the Apple documentation, this seems OK, however does UIKit *remove* constraints automatically before calling this function?

I am finding that this works OK but I am concerned that I am just re-adding the same type of constraints.

When does UIKit remove constraints automatically or doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `updateConstraints` does not remove any constraints you added. If you want to avoid adding duplicate constraints, you need to set a flag or keep references to the constraints you already created.

Answer (score 2):

Constraints are for laying out user interface elements, so in normal situations it does not get deleted.

Following are few situations when a constraint is automatically removed or it just isn't satisfied by the constraint solver:

- when all the views that the constraint is attached to are removed
- in case there is a conflicting constraint, *but* you will see such an error

  > Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

I normally add constraints when the view is initialized, such as:

- `viewDidLoad` of `UIViewController`
- `init` of `UIView` thats subclassed and does not have a storyboard xib
- `awakeFromNib` of `UIView` thats subclassed and does have a storyboard

Comment: A conflicting constraint isn't removed. It is just left unsatisfied by the constraint solver.